# Confusion on using Z-distribution or Chi-squared

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, chi-squared-test, z-score

I have two questions in front of me, first is :

- A random sample of size 35 is selected from a population that is normally distributed. If the mean and the standard deviation of the sample is 75 and 8.5, respectively, then find the probability that the mean of the population is more than 78.5.

and second one is :

- A random sample of size 16 is selected from a population that is normally distributed. If the variance of the sample is 27.6, then find the probability that the variance of the population is more than 29.

this questions looked similar to me however, we solve the first one with **z-score** and second one with **chi-squared distribution** formula, I could not figure out how to differenciate this two questions. How can I see the difference ?

Comment: If this is a question from a textbook, course, or test used for a class or self-study, could you add the `self-study` tag?

Comment: Also, note that  `the mean of the population` and `the variance of a population` are constants; perhaps you mean "the mean of the sample" and the variance of the sample resp.? Actually, re-reading your question I'm not sure what are you asking about. Are you interested in doing inference on a population parameter, e.g. mean, variance, given the observed sample? Once the sample has been observed, the probability of whatever statement can only be 0 or 1.

Comment: @utobi - I think that is just a bad question.  We are told the mean and variance of the first sample and the variance of the second sample, so the question is presumably about the $p$-values of these given the stated hypotheses about the population statistics

Comment: Neither question can be answered with the information given: unless you assume the mean and variance of the population are random variables and make strong assumptions about the distributions of those variables, the sample does not suffice to estimate those probabilities.